# Exclude variables based on pattern and melt

Tags: r, data.table

My data look like this

```
   id   var1    var1_a  var2    var2_a  var3    var3_a
   1    1         7       7       8      9         4
   2    2         4       8       7      6         5
   3    5         5       1       2      3         4
   4    6         9       5       6      7         8
```

I want to select var1, var2, and var3 only, and exclude var1_a, var2_a an var3_a. Name of variables may vary in length

I know I can use something like

`dt.m<-melt(dt, id=1, measure.vars=c(1, 3, 5), na.rm=TRUE)`

but I don't want to use this approach because I have too many of variables.

How ca I do this using patterns or a similar approach?

Comment: Subsetting columns like that is a completely separate issue from `melt`ing them. I think you could simplify this question to be just *"subset dataframe based on pattern"* ... and then be clear what the pattern or anti-pattern is. For instance, `dt[, grep("_", colnames(dt), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)]` might be enough to feed into your `melt` command.

Comment: Thanks. Thi is what I did ```a<-grep("_", colnames(dt), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE) ``` and then 

```dt.m<-dt[,..a]```

Answer (score 2):

If the measure column names have a pattern to them then use `grep` to find which they are.  In the example, the variables of interest all end in a digit so we could use this:

```
melt(dt, id = 1, measure = grep("\\d$", names(dt)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

or if the columns of interest are in predictable positions use `seq` or similar approach to generate the column numbers.

```
melt(dt, id = 1, measure = seq(2, 6, 2), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Other ways to pick out the names that work in the example are:

```
# pick out column names that have 4 characters
which(nchar(names(dt)) == 4)

# pick out names having no underscore and that are not first
grep("_", names(dt), invert = TRUE)[-1]

# pick out even positions
which( (1:ncol(dt)) %% 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'd comment but I don't have enough rep yet. If your variables are actually named var1 var1_a, etc, you can use gsub

```
names1 = paste0("var",seq(1,100))
names2 = paste0("var",seq(1,100),"_a")
names = sample(c(names1, names2))

x = matrix(rnorm(200*10),nrow=10)
d = data.frame(x)
names(d) = names

d.m <- d[,which(gsub("_a","",names(d)) == names(d))]
print(names(d.m))
```